# How to pull the latest commit git with submodule's update init

Tags: git, repository, git-submodules

I have a git-managed project called `myProject` which contains a submodule called `mySubmodule`.

There is a point in our pipeline where we clone the whole `myProject` and then we run this git command: `git submodule update --init --recursive --remote`. But it looks like it doesn't pull the latest state from the original submodule's repo. We have to manually update `mySubmodule` with `git submodule update --remote --merge`, then push it to `myProject`. I would like to use this submodule the way when my pipeline is freshly checking out `myProject` then the update would init this submodule with the submodule's latest state. Is that possible?

Comment: I'll leave the question unanswered myself because there might be something in the newest submodule setup for this, but *generally* the answer here is no: that's not how submodules are *intended* to be used. The design says that whoever makes a commit in the superproject has *already decided exactly which commits are to be used in every submodule*, and from then on, everyone uses *those* commits. This is precisely the same as the model of using Git *without* a submodule: the set of files you commit are the set of files to be used. There's no "oh except update foo.txt".

Comment: This fact is why [tag:repo] exists in the first place, for instance. Lots of groups have invented or re-invented the "better way to do submodules" idea.

Comment: @torek so do you say I always have to set mySubmodules's commit in myProject, to know which commit to init and cannot have a general solution for setting it to the latest one? (I mean regular git) It's fair then.

Comment: I left this unanswered because there's ongoing work on `git submodule` and there might now, or soon, be something that you find to your liking. But the original design from about 17 years ago requires that you do this manually, and that still works and will continue to work.